# I need to fix my update to the dynamic jTable by a search in my Access database

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a problem in updating my single jtable from Microsoft Access Database.
I do not have any error messages. I tried out the Query for the database using like, but my jtable does not populate in relation to the data stored in the database.

```
public TableModel setAuthorSearchEjournalTableValues(){
            String eJournalAuthor = jTextField30.getText();
            ResultSet tableData = DCE.searchEjournalbyAuthor(eJournalAuthor);
            try {
            ResultSetMetaData md = tableData.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = md.getColumnCount();
            Vector columns = new Vector(columnCount);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                    columns.add(md.getColumnName(i));
                }


            Vector data = new Vector();
            Vector row;

            while (tableData.next()) {

            row = new Vector(columnCount);
                for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                row.addElement( tableData.getString(i) );

            }
            data.add(row);
            }
            DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
            return tableModel;

        //Debugging                

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

}`
```

And my result retrieving query is here

```
public ResultSet searchEjournalbyAuthor(String author){
            conn = Connect();
            try{
                String myQuery = "select AuthorDetails,Year,Titleofarticle,Journaltitle,volume,pagenumbers,URL,AccessedDate from Ejournalcitation where AuthorDetails = '"+author+"'";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(myQuery);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();
                return rs;
            }catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

with the code to display as

```
private void jTextField30KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==0&&jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==0){//BookTitle
            jTable1.setModel(setTitleSearchBookTableValues());
        }
        else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==0&&jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==1){//BookAuthor
            jTable1.setModel(setAuthorSearchBookTableValues());
        }
        else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==1&&jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==0){//WebSiteTitle
            jTable1.setModel(setTitleSearchWebSiteTableValues());
        }
        else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==1&&jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==1){//WebSiteAuthor
            jTable1.setModel(setAuthorSearchWebSiteTableValues());
        }
        else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==2&&jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==0){//Ejournaltitle
            jTable1.setModel(setTitleSearchEjournalTableValues());
        }
        else if(jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()==3&&jComboBox2.getSelectedIndex()==1){//EjournalAuthor
            jTable1.setModel(setAuthorSearchEjournalTableValues());
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a value and select the type of search");
        }
}
```

Help me out!! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you must include

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

with the corrected query

`String myQuery = "select AuthorDetails,Year,Titleofarticle,Journaltitle,volume,pagenumbers,URL,AccessedDate from Ejournalcitation where AuthorDetails like '%"+author+"%'";`